# Как подключить к одной базе данных localDB два проекта в одном решении?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

В одном проекте заполняется база данных с моделью, нужно в другом проекте их взять. Что нужно для этого настроить что бы база с моделью была видна?

Comment: Обычно в таком случае выделяют в общий проект (а то и не один, скажем, DataAccess и Core) работу с базой, а затем подключают к нужным проектам (вы их описали как "два проекта в решении").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LocalDB (если вы используете его именно как LocalDB, а не как SQL Express + Attach DB FileName - это экземпляр уровня пользователя, а не уровня приложения. Просто используйте тот же connection string - и другое приложение будет видеть базу. Вы даже можете подключится к LocalDB из SQL Server Management Studio. Единственное отличие от полноценного экземпляра SQL Server - существование на уровне юзера, а не на уровне машины.

Если вы используете Attach DB FileName - подключитесь к LocalDB через SQL Server Management Studio, с тем же именем экземляра, но без указания AttachDB FileName, и сделайте постоянный Attach через контекстное меню. После этого оба проекта будут видеть базу просто при указании ее имени в Connection String, а не по полному пути к файлу.

Если вопрос про работу с базой в рамках одного Solution - приаттачте базу на постоянной основе (или создайте новую, через тот же SSMS), вынесите код работы с базой в отдельный общий проект, и добавьте на него референс в обоих существующих проектах.